# Uniq element extraction

Tags: bash, shell, unique

I have a tab delimited file which looks like this:

```
ABCA2   chr9    139021506   139043195
ABCA2   chr9    139021506   139042561
ABCC1   chr16   15950934    16144431
ABCC1   chr16   15950934    16144431
ABCC1   chr16   15950934    16144431
ABCC1   chr16   15950934    16144431
```

I want to extract the values based on column , like the values of `ABCA2` in column 2,3, and 4 should be extracted only once  and that is the first time the name occurs in column1.

The desirable output is:

```
ABCA2   chr9    139021506   139043195
ABCC1   chr16   15950934    16144431
```

Thank you

Comment: Which one of python or bash have you tried?

Comment: @khalid: I was trying cut -f1 | uniq  ... but it doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: The question is a little confusing as your desired output is not what you are looking for, the first 3 lines in your file should be outputted, unless you are looking for the first occurence of the value in col1 and the subsequent columns of data it contains ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement of your problem is ambiguous, but I am interpreting it to mean that you only want a line to be output if the entry in its first column has not yet been seen.  I don't know why this is tagged `python`, since awk is clearly the right tool:

```
awk '{if( !seen[$1]++ ) print }' input-file
```

or, more simply

```
awk '! a[$1]++' input-file
```

Comment: awk '{if( !seen[$1]++ ) print }' input-file   this is what I meant, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using your example input in  `file.txt`, `uniq --check-chars=5 file.txt` gives this output:

```
ABCA2 chr9 139021506 139043195
ABCC1 chr16 15950934 16144431
```

As you can see it is limited to comparing only the first 5 characters of each line.

*Edit*:

As William Pursell pointed out, `uniq` assumes that the file is already sorted. An alternative is to use `sort`:

```
$ sort --key=1,1 --unique file.txt
ABCA2 chr9 139021506 139043195
ABCC1 chr16 15950934 16144431
$
```

*Be sure to notice William Pursells comment below:* Sorting of the input data is not strictly necessary to solve the problem as stated. If speed is a concern/data volume is large, a linear solution memorizing seen keys (such as the `awk` soultion in Williams answer) is better.

Comment: Note that this assumes the input is already sorted on the first column

Comment: @WilliamPursell: That is correct, thanks for poiting it out. I just updated the answer with an example using `sort`.

Comment: This is en aesthetically appealing solution, but since it is getting more votes than the awk solution, I think it's good to point out that the sort is unnecessary work.  In particular, on my system running the two solutions on /usr/share/dict/words, awk runs more than 3 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> with open('f.txt') as f:
...    for line in f.readlines():
...        x = line.split()
...        if x[0] not in d.keys():
...           d[x[0]] = x[1:]
...
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...    print k,' '.join(v)
...
ABCA2 chr9 139021506 139043195
ABCC1 chr16 15950934 16144431
```